# Wireless Not Connecting/Dropping Connection

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 14.04, realtek

I've searched around and nothing seems to be up to date.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 on a Toshiba Satellite S50.

My WiFi detects the network, but keeps asking for a password and saying "You have been disconnected".  My WiFi device is a RealTek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter, for which none of the drivers I've downloaded have been able to compile on the newer kernel.

I tried plugging in a cheap USB WiFi dongle, and I was able to connect, however my connection seemed to drop out every few minutes and not come back until I reseated the WiFi dongle.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  praseodym over at ubuntu forums.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)     
build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r firmware/* /lib/firmware
echo "options rtl8188ee ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
```

fixed the problem for me.  Seems this person's repo had a branch updated for compiling on 14.04 and I was able to compile the firmware correctly this time.

Note: Had to run make twice as it ran into a directory not found problem for a directory it was creating.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219952

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it using the command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

Comment: You may want to add detail, such as what the command actually does (which I personally deem very important whenever giving commands involving elevated privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Ubuntu Software Center, navigate to "Edit > Software Sources > Additional Drivers" and see if the system can detect any additional drivers.

Comment: Only video card drivers showing up.